# Elasticsearch Collapsing Based on Text Similarity

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working with Elasticsearch and trying to come up with a way to filter a text field based on a phrase. I have basic searching working, but I also want to collapse "similar" results rather than duplicating them.

For example, given 5 objects with text content as

- Buy 1 car get one car free until March
- Buy 1 car get one car free until April
- 50% off your car insurance when you buy through us
- Get 50% off your oven

If searching for `car` then I'd be looking for 2 results:

- 50% off your car insurance [...]
- EITHER of the 1st or 2nd one (with both showing in `inner_hits`)

I've tried to do this using collapse on the `content` field but that will only collapse on exact matches.

```php
    'query' => [
        'match' => [
            'content' => 'car',
        ],
    ],
    'collapse' => [
        'field' => 'content',
        'inner_hits' => [
            'name' => 'recently_seen_on',
            'size' => 3,
            'sort' => [['seen_on' => 'desc']],
         ],
     ],
```

I've also tried creating adding a similarity property to the `content` field but I couldn't figure out if it's possible to collapse using that.

I also come across this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-bucket-significanttext-aggregation.html but when I tried something similar I got 0 result. I set the `content` type to `keywords` in the mappings:

```php
[
    'content' => ['type' => 'keyword'],
]
```

And then using:

```php
'query' => [
    'match' => [
        'content' => 'car',
    ],
],
'aggs' => [
    'keywords' => [
        'significant_text' => [
            'field' => 'content',
            'filter_duplicate_text' => true,
        ],
    ],
],
```

Is achieving something like this possible without coming adding a field that groups fields based on content manually?